# How can I redirect a user back to the registration page, but with red asterisks next to required fields?

Tags: node.js, express

My goal is simple.  If a user is attempting to register and clicks "submit" before all required fields are full, I want to redirect him or her back to the registration page, but change it slightly so that a red asterisk appears next to each required field (this is an arbitrary and ugly choice, I know). I imagine I don't have to have a separate view just for this purpose.  Is it possible to alter the registration view in this way?

In routes.js

```
// process the signup form
    app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/signup?missingFields=true', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));
```

In signup.ejs

```
% if (req.params.missingFields) {%>
        BLAH
    <% } %>
```

I get an error in signup.ejs "req is not defined at eval"  Here is the full error text:

> ReferenceError: /home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/views/signup.ejs:26 24| --> 25| >> 26| <% if (req.params.missingFields) {%> 27| BLAH 28| <% } %> 29|  req is not defined at eval (eval at  (/home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:237:14), :31:825) at eval (eval at  (/home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:237:14), :31:2194) at /home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:250:15 at Object.exports.render (/home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:288:13) at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:318:20) at View.render (/home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8) at Function.app.render (/home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:502:10) at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:777:7) at Object.handle (/home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/routes/routes.js:35:7) at next_layer (/home/adam/Documents/Node/node-authentication/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)

Comment: why are `mongodb` and `passport` tags included?

Comment: I'm using those and I thought there might be some package for either that I was unaware of that could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be checking the data before you post or send your user over to another place. Once you deem the data to be correct and passed of all validation checks, you can post it.

You can use simple ajax to check the fields lively and put the asterisk next to the field.

If however for some reason you are unable to do so, you can redirect the user using

`res.redirect('/path')`

and to put the asterisk use

`res.redirect('/path?errorInField1=true')`

you can than get that data with `req.params.errorInField1` and act appropriately

Comment: I understand how to do that, I am asking how can I redirect them back to the registration page, but change how it looks.  I'm realizing now I should probably just do it in client side JS.

Comment: Added that part to the answer :)

Comment: Then do I need to use decodeURIComponent to check the GET variable from the browser?

Comment: no no no, use `req.params.theIdInTheUrlThatYouWantTheValueOf`

Comment: I'm still not quite getting it.  How do I send req back to the browser? Should any JS file running in /path have access to the req object?

Comment: res and req are the parameters taken as a callback from a route

Comment: If I redirect as you said, how can I use req.params to check the value on the client side?  I am using the template ejs and <% req.params %> is null.

Comment: I don't use ejs but you need to do req.params.field. req.params itself will return an object of fields. You can check the field you want with regular if statements.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. req.params.missingField is null in the template.

Comment: Does your URL look somewhat like this: domain.com?field=value&another field=another value because its what req.params looks at

Comment: Updated my post with more details

Answer (score 1):

Create an post method for the get method of the page. First install body parser to get the post values.

```
$ npm install --save body-parser
```

And then initialize it.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Now validate the user input.

```
router.post('/register' function(req, res){
    var email = req.body.email;
    var name = req.body.name;
    ..... // Other required fields.
    if(email || name ...//Other variables to validate for null){
        req.flash('error', 'All the fields are required completing');
        req.redirect()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the validation in the client.

In my opinion,submit the request via ajax will be better,if you submit form,you have to redirect back when some error occur.